# ATmega328/P - Modes of Operation

Tags: atmega

Is it possible to place the ATmega328/P microcontroller into kernel mode versus user mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The 8-bit AVR core does not have any privileged modes or instructions. Nor does it have a MPU so there is no kernel vs user mode distinction.